# My object is coming out as gray despite its assigned color being white. Other objects don't have this issue. What am I missing?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, objects, color

I'll preface this with a few things. This project is being run in Cycles Render. I am a beginner when it comes to using Blender, so please forgive me for obvious errors.

I cannot make my rendered object (a triangle) fully white no matter what I do. Instead, it is gray. I'm not sure what I have enabled that is preventing it from appearing as white instead of gray. Other objects remain white, so I know it isn't so much a scene or lighting issue. I can shift the color as well, but it keeps its gray hue it seems.

**Pictures:**

Note: Both Viewport Color and Viewport Specular hex values are FFFFFF (whitest, brightest white).

This picture shows the triangle selected. Note that the color on the left indicates it is fully white (in the node as well).
[image]

The second image here has one of the white bars selected. It has identical an color swatch as the triangle. Why are these bars white yet not the triangle?
[image]

Each of those bars is its own object, though I understand how it may be misleading.

[image]

**Does anyone know what I am missing?**

Comment: It looks like you got 2 meshes there. Remove the one without a material.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? There's another triangle mesh within this triangle? I can move it freely and I find no other object hidden in the same space.

Comment: Whoops Mr. Zak, I should have clarified. Each of those bars is its own object, though I understand how it could have been misleading. [Here is a picture](https://i.imgur.com/r5By3Wv.png)

Comment: @Nightowl can you edit your images to show the material surface values, not the viewport settings?

Comment: It is hard to find then the reason for difference. Note though that Material shading isn't what is going to be rendered and is mainly approximation (though it still should be the same for both materials). If exact values for Material shading are important I think you should attach a copy of the blend file here, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to do this

Comment: @Sazerac
The Viewport color and Viewport Specular hex values are both FFFFFF.

Comment: @MrZak
I'm unsure of any ongoing shading effects for any of the objects. 
What is the purpose of the website you've linked?

Comment: The https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ was linked because I asked you to provide a copy of your blend file shared here (not necessarily full project rather blend which allows to reproduce what you experience). Note also to look into answer you received as it might be the solution.

Comment: @MrZak [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6028" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6028/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Looking at your blend, the maximum draw type of your triangle is set to solid, for it to be drawn correctly you need to set it to textured. It can be found under the object tab (orange cube icon).

You need to change the actual material colours to affect the render. These can be found under the *surface* heading on the materials tab rather than the *settings* heading, or in the node editor.

[image]

The viewport colours you are changing are just that, colours used in the viewport to differentiate between objects, and have no affect on the render.

Comment: Good to know. I can see the preview object (that sphere) change its color, yet I don't know how to make that affect the object in material view in the 3D window. Any changes I make don't seem to do anything with my selected object.

Comment: @Nightowl found another issue and updated

Comment: Switching to textured resolved my issue! Thank you.

As a quick addition before I leave: If I'd like to automate this surface color and have it change live in the 3D view window, should I still automate it from Properties > Material > Surface > Color, or is there a different color picker I should select? I only ask because a quick check of automating this location yields no results.

Comment: @Nightowl for simple diffuse only materials that would work, but materials can be much much more complex that that. It is probably worth learning how to use the material node editor.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again.